# Displaying a video through the web whilst hiding the location

Tags: web-browser, source-code, obfuscation

I felt this fit more here than SO, if not, please vote to migrate.

We've been approached by a company who would like to use our platform to host their videos. The issue is that right now, we use the HTML5 `<video>` tag meaning anyone who is capable of opening the source of a page can see the actual location of the video.

They're not comfortable (and rightfully so) with allowing their content to be downloaded by anyone viewing the page. While I realize that keeping it 100% secure is impossible, what steps can I take to make the content harder to get at?

We host the videos from Amazon S3, meaning we already have access to access tokens. My first thought was to set a reasonably low expiration time on the content so any attempts to access the file at a later date would fail.

I know [Brightcove](http://www.brightcove.com/en/) handle this sort of security through flash, if it comes to using flash and rtmp, which paths would I need to take?

**Technologies already used:**

- Amazon S3
- PHP
- Apache
- HTML5 Video

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible.  You could use a streaming server to send it over RTMP or even put some DRM on it to make it harder to play outside of a secured player, but the stream can always be ripped if it goes to a client's computer and DRM is just a small hurdle to be overcome by a determined attacker.

You seem to be aware that it is impossible though, so the recommendations still hold.  Using RTMP (or similar) would make it so that someone would have to use a stream ripper rather than a simple progressive download.  DRM on top of that would put a further barrier, however both of these impose on the client side options as well.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer. I'm looking for a way to hinder would be downloaders, but have minimal impact on genuine clients, so I guess RTMP would be a viable option. It would at least stop people saving the file directly from inside the browser/player. When it comes to DRM, the only experiences I've had are through game retailers, what kind of things would I need to be looking at?

Comment: @JamieTaylor - There are actually secure stream servers available.  They use a key handled by a trusted player, but require more complex clients, so they probably extend beyond being useful for you.  I think there is DRM support in HTML5, but I don't know much about how it works in that particular context.

Comment: Thanks, I'd rather keep with the services we currently use but I'm sure AWS Cloudfront offers something like this. If there aren't any more answers posted soon, I'll mark this as correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is a proposal for [DRM in HTML5](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/encrypted-media/encrypted-media.html) which is currently supported in [some](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [browsers](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/826991846). This is used by e.g. [Netflix](http://techblog.netflix.com/2013/04/html5-video-at-netflix.html).

Flash supports [RTMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol). Microsoft Silverlight [supports DRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838192%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) as well, but be aware that none of these technologies work cross-platform (yet). Also, as shown in the past such protection [can be bypassed](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/rtmp_dump_helper.html).

Of course, you could try to build a little obfuscation yourself as well.